# Laravel 4 Redirect with global styling

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Does anyone know where and how to style the redirect with global such as:

```
return Redirect::route('home')
                    ->with('global', 'Your content has been posted!');
```

I want to use the bootstrap alerts with the global message

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to put the styling after the global

Here is what I did:

```
return Redirect::route('admin-console-post')
                    ->with('global', '
                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                          Your content has been posted successfully!
                        </div>
                        ');
```

Comment: @Chase please put details of your solution such as the code you used to fix it for others to gain something from your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to style it in view like this:

```
@if(Session::has('global'))
   <div class="output">
       {{ Session::get('global') }}
   </div>       
@endif
```

Where output is class in which you put style of your choice.
Hope it helps ^^.